# Sharing sensitive Chrome Browser info between Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, google-chrome

**The Scenario:** Several sites that I log onto frequently require me to register my computer using Google Chrome as a "safe" Home computer such as my bank and my work website. I.E. {Trust this PC as my Home Computer}, so the next time I log on to my bank, I don't have to use 2 factor authorization, and re verify my identity each time I visit.

**The Question:** Is it somehow possible to "share" this cookie or whatever it adds between Ubuntu and Windows for each OS and what would be the most efficient and **secure**, (if any) way to do this?

Comment: It does not sync that info nor would I want it too under my google account.

Answer (score 1):

Most such identifications note your computer name as well as your operating system(and the browser of course). So, it seems to be nearly impossible.